# Why switch from HttpClient version 3 to 4

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

My Java application is developed using HttpClient 3. Is there any advantages of switching to version 4?

Is there a changelog. article, blog entry or something that describes what's new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the release notes: http://www.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/RELEASE_NOTES.txt

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit embarrassed. I only searched for "changelog" :)